# Getting "node.popperRef is not a function" when tring to use popper and tippy with cytoscape to create a tooltip

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, popper.js

while trying to achieve a similar function of ***showing a tooltip when clicking on a node***, I tried to modify the demo on [*https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-popper#usage-with-tippyjs*](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-popper#usage-with-tippyjs)

But I keep getting the error message: "node.popperRef is not a function"

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>学习Cytoscape.js和neo4j</title>
    <link href="/static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

    
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2/dist/umd/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@6/dist/tippy-bundle.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-popper@2.0.0/cytoscape-popper.js"></script>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.18.2/cytoscape.min.js" integrity="sha512-CBGCXtszkG5rYlQSTNUzk54/731Kz28WPk2uT1GCPCqgfVRJ2v514vzzf16HuGX9WVtE7JLqRuAERNAzFZ9Hpw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.18.2/cytoscape.umd.js" integrity="sha512-Sj2IibbEYxNWMtZ7mxdAplO062HJ2oe2/be8VCvIfZofl1iXsqH+9lwIf60jm/PKAFs/+fDsVUPtZuH86Kx1qg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.18.2/cytoscape.umd.min.js" integrity="sha512-WaLQ3SSNa6TgZwE7M2y4xKorsywIDHKQQz0swoF2dun2sFYkMrajr4M4anuw69n6mUPMPQdivAxtcf0kXgfsow==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/code.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button data-tippy-content="Tooltip">Text</button>
        <button data-tippy-content="Another Tooltip">Text</button>
    </div>
        <div id="cy"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

MY js:

```
$(function () {

/*return a json*/
var style1 = $.get('/static/js', function(json){
    /*console.log(json)*/
    return json;})

$.get('/graph', function (result) {
    var style = [
    { selector: 'node[label = "Person"]', css: {'background-color': '#6FB1FC'}},
    { selector: 'node[label = "Movie"]', css: {'background-color': '#F5A45D'}}
    ];
    
    var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
        container: document.getElementById('cy'),
        style: style1,
        layout: { name: 'cose' },      
        elements: result.elements,
        zoom: 1
    });

    let node = cy.nodes().first();
    let ref = node.popperRef();
    console.log(ref);

    tippy('button', {
        content: 'hello',
        trigger: 'click',
    });

    cy.on('tap', 'node', function (evt) {
        var node = evt.target;
        var t = tippy(node, {
            placement: 'bottom',
            hideOnClick: false,
            trigger: 'click',
            interactive: true,
            content: 'birthday: ' + node.data('born')
        });
        console.log(t);
        console.log('tapped ' + node.data());
        console.log('tapped ' + node.data('name'));
        console.log('tapped ' + node.data('born'));
    });

    function makeTippy(node){
        console.log('进入makeTippy函数');
        console.log(node);
        var ref = node.popperRef();
        console.log(ref);
        var t = tippy('node', {
          onCreate: function(instance){ // mandatory
            instance.popperInstance.reference = ref;
          },
          placement: 'bottom',
          /*followCursor: 'true',*/
          hideOnClick: false,
          trigger: 'manual', 
          interactive: true,
          content: 'birthday: ' + node.id
        });
        console.log(t);
        return t;
    };
});
```

});

ps: In js, $.get('/graph', function (result){}, the result from '/graph' is a jsonify from python flask, containing nodes and edges data from a neo4j server, which is supposed to be used in cytoscape's constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem with importing scripts in your HTML code. They look very weird to me. Try below.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape-popper/cytoscape-popper.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@6"></script>
```

Comment: First 2 importing scripts return 404 error, that's why I wrote HTML in that way. But I solve my problems myself by using popper1.14.7 and tippy5 instead of newer version.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problems myself by using popper1.14.7 and tippy5 instead of newer version.
Follow is my new HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>学习Cytoscape.js和neo4j</title>
    <link href="/static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-popper@1.0.5/cytoscape-popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@5/dist/tippy-bundle.iife.js"></script>

    <script src="/static/js/code.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="cy"></div>
</body>
</html>
```